# Scraping multiple links with Selenium: How to handle expired links and avoid stopping the scraping process

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, 
TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import json

data = []
driver_path = 
"C:\\Users\Engineer_Stephen\\Downloads\\Compressed\\chromedriver"
service = Service(driver_path)


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, 
options=chrome_options)

links  = ['link1','link1','link1','link1','link1','link1']

for link in links:
    try:
     driver.get(link)
     wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 80)
     map_element = 
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
        '//span[@class="contour-HazardInfo-name montage- 
        Text"]')))
     disaster = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
      '//span[@class="contour-HazardInfo-name montage-Text"]')
     info = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='contour- 
     TabBarItem-label montage-Text']")
     types = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-montage- 
     id='type']")
     description = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
     "//label/span[contains(text(), 'Description')]")
    descriptionText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
    '//div[@class="contour-HazardInfo-descriptionText montage- 
    Text"]')

    data.append({
        'disaster': disaster.text,
        'info': info.text,
        'type': types.text,
        'description': description.text,
        'descriptionText': descriptionText.text
    })
   except NoSuchElementException:
       print(f"Data not available for link: {link}")
   except TimeoutException:
       print(f"Timeout occurred for link: {link}")
       driver.quit()
    continue
   except Exception as e:
     print(f"An error occurred for link: {link}")
     print(str(e))
     driver.quit()
     continue

driver.quit()

resource = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print(resource)
```

The stack trace is like this:

> Timeout occurred for link: https://disasteralert.pdc.org/disasteralert/?hazard_id=202739
>
> An error occurred for link: [https://disasteralert.pdc.org/disasteralert/?hazard_id=202738\](https://disasteralert.pdc.org/disasteralert/?hazard_id=202738%5C)
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=33660): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/99df58ee2824dbdf4720427db546798d/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000027446C07A00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

It only shows the connection timeout for the first expired link and it can not continue providing the second exception for the remaining links

I have provided a sample of links I want to scrap. I have discovered that some of the links have expired. I am struggling to improve this code to make it close the current window of the expired link and go to the next link may you  please help

I am expecting the code to scrap data from the listed links in the list. If the link is expired and it means it is going to hit the timeout exception. I want Selenium to close that browser window and go to the next link which means opening another browser window and scraping the data.

Answer (score 0):

A superficial analysis of that webpage shows source of actual info being `https://hpxml.pdc.org/public.xml`, an endpoint which is accessed regularly to refresh the info in the page with map etc.

This is one way to obtain that information:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_xml('https://hpxml.pdc.org/public.xml')
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    app_ID  app_IDs     autoexpire  category_ID     charter_Uri     comment_Text    create_Date_hst     create_Date     creator     end_Date_hst    ...     start_Date_hst  start_Date  status  type_ID     update_Date_hst     update_Date     product_total   uuid    description     update_User
0   0   NaN     Y   EVENT   NaN     D2P2 auto-generated Earthquake Hazard   2023-05-28T03:11:24-10:00   2023-05-28T13:11:24-10:00   D2P2    2023-05-29T03:11:24-10:00   ...     2023-05-28T02:52:39-10:00   2023-05-28T12:52:39-10:00   A   EARTHQUAKE  2023-05-28T03:11:24-10:00   2023-05-28T13:11:24-10:00   1   e3b44cd0-503c-4c2a-b49e-8aedad507cfa    An earthquake with a magnitude of 5.1 at a dep...   None
1   0   NaN     Y   EVENT   NaN     352090  2023-05-18T03:50:52-10:00   2023-05-18T13:50:52-10:00   D2P2    2023-06-01T15:20:43-10:00   ...     2023-05-18T03:39:59-10:00   2023-05-18T13:39:59-10:00   A   VOLCANO     2023-05-28T03:00:52-10:00   2023-05-28T13:00:52-10:00   59  474b0157-761d-43fd-b8a5-24854683f437    Volcanic activity has been reported for Sangay...   None
2   0   NaN     Y   EVENT   NaN     FLOODIPAWS-WARNING-2023-McCook, NE  2023-05-26T06:08:49-10:00   2023-05-26T16:08:49-10:00   D2P2    2023-05-28T19:14:59-10:00   ...     2023-05-26T13:01:59-10:00   2023-05-26T23:01:59-10:00   A   FLOOD   2023-05-28T02:35:24-10:00   2023-05-28T12:35:24-10:00   16  779627e6-d4e6-4d9e-9980-bda8d0905d20    The National Weather Service (NWS) has issued ...   None
3   0   NaN     Y   EVENT   NaN     D2P2 auto-generated Earthquake Hazard   2023-05-27T20:10:31-10:00   2023-05-28T06:10:31-10:00   D2P2    2023-05-28T20:15:00-10:00   ...     2023-05-27T19:49:56-10:00   2023-05-28T05:49:56-10:00   A   EARTHQUAKE  2023-05-27T20:15:00-10:00   2023-05-28T06:15:00-10:00   2   a0370397-66e7-4d2e-91f6-e844904779b0    An earthquake with a magnitude of 5.2 at a dep...   None
4   0   NaN     Y   EVENT   NaN     282080  2023-05-01T09:40:52-10:00   2023-05-01T19:40:52-10:00   D2P2    2023-06-02T01:50:44-10:00   ...     2023-05-01T09:32:59-10:00   2023-05-01T19:32:59-10:00   A   VOLCANO     2023-05-28T01:50:45-10:00   2023-05-28T11:50:45-10:00   62  f1e4fe5b-7e99-4f2b-aafc-77ed09d8ae00    Volcanic activity has been reported for Aira i...   None
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
143     0   NaN     N   EVENT   NaN     None    2023-04-25T21:56:45-10:00   2023-04-26T07:56:45-10:00   jmyhre  2023-05-02T21:54:18-10:00   ...     2023-04-25T21:54:18-10:00   2023-04-26T07:54:18-10:00   A   BIOMEDICAL  2023-04-25T21:56:45-10:00   2023-04-26T07:56:45-10:00   1   7f27c603-47ad-4622-ad1c-0c38cd40094d    A measles outbreak has been reported in parts ...   jmyhre
144     0   NaN     N   EVENT   NaN     NaN     2022-10-05T07:16:01-10:00   2022-10-05T17:16:01-10:00   amontoro    2022-10-21T07:08:35-10:00   ...     2022-10-05T07:08:35-10:00   2022-10-05T17:08:35-10:00   A   BIOMEDICAL  2022-11-28T10:21:15-10:00   2022-11-28T20:21:15-10:00   32  52e8b82a-3719-4f0b-9ea8-e66e2ab0f432    Cholera outbreak has been reported in parts of...   jmyhre
145     0   NaN     N   EVENT   NaN     None    2023-03-10T15:03:32-10:00   2023-03-11T01:03:32-10:00   jmyhre  2023-03-17T15:01:46-10:00   ...     2023-03-10T15:01:46-10:00   2023-03-11T01:01:46-10:00   A   DROUGHT     2023-03-10T15:03:32-10:00   2023-03-11T01:03:32-10:00   1   4a1e1e72-ce4c-4a34-88bd-63b8c498089f    Drought warnings have been reported for Djibou...   jmyhre
146     0   NaN     N   EVENT   NaN     None    2023-02-24T13:36:34-10:00   2023-02-24T23:36:34-10:00   jmyhre  2023-03-03T13:33:11-10:00   ...     2023-02-24T13:33:11-10:00   2023-02-24T23:33:11-10:00   A   BIOMEDICAL  2023-02-24T13:36:34-10:00   2023-02-24T23:36:34-10:00   1   6882129b-e06a-4ac7-bd53-6b874b1026f7    Cholera outbreak has been reported in parts of...   jmyhre
147     0   NaN     N   EVENT   NaN     https://www.who.int/emergencies/disease-outbre...   2022-08-25T18:12:26-10:00   2022-08-26T04:12:26-10:00   jmyhre  2022-09-01T18:10:04-10:00   ...     2022-08-25T18:10:04-10:00   2022-08-26T04:10:04-10:00   A   BIOMEDICAL  2022-08-25T18:12:26-10:00   2022-08-26T04:12:26-10:00   1   4207506c-4e19-4dcb-b268-d291023b2acd    PDC continues to work closely with partners th...   jmyhre

148 rows × 33 columns
```

You can find pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

Comment: thank you so much i scrapped it using bs4 and requests